# Error gem install libv8 on CentOS6.7

Tags: gcc, rubygems, bundle, centos6

I am encountered a gem install error in CentOS6.7
But when I use `gcc -version` it show the version of gcc is 4.4.7.

Here is the error information:

> Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb creating Makefile Compiling v8 for ia32
>   Using python 2.6.6 Using compiler: /usr/bin/c++ (GCC version
>   1.5.0) Unable to find a compiler officially supported by v8. It is recommended to use GCC v4.4 or higher
>   /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:28:in
>   make_flags': undefined method include?' for nil:NilClass
>   (NoMethodError)
>           from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:56:in
>   block in build_libv8!'
>           from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:49:in
>   chdir'
>           from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/builder.rb:49:in
>   build_libv8!'
>           from /home/git/gitlab/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.7/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in
>   install!'
>           from extconf.rb:7:in '

Answer (score 0):

libv8 maintainer here.

Could you please try again after updating libv8 to the latest 3.16 version available?

If you continue receiving an error, please consider opening an issue with more info about your system and the `gcc --version` output of your compiler in libv8's issue tracker: https://github.com/cowboyd/libv8/issues

As a side note, you should consider asking the maintainers of a project directly first, through their issue tracker for example, before shooting a question in SO. Your question probably would have remained unanswered had I not been by chance looking for recent questions about libv8 here.